# What is the meaning of N bit key-size

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I read about the Key_size in Cryptography but i don't understand exactly that what is the specific meaning of Key size? 
for example in wikipedia saied:

> "Triple DES has a key size of 168 bits but provides at most 112 bits
>   of security, since an attack of complexity 2^112 is known"

Is this mean that if we brute force 2^112 times then we can crack all of 3DES hashes? 
What is the difference between 128 bit encryption and 1024 bit encryption?

Comment: 168 bit key means DES  cipher with 168 bit

Comment: Triple DES is not a hash function so it does not generate hashes. It depends on the attack if you can simply try all 2^112 possibilities to crack the plaintext. If the plaintext is a random then you may not have anything to test the decryption result against. Finally, this question is completely off topic here as it does not specify anything to do with programming, and the quality of the answers may reflect that (and up to now probably do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Let's take this one at a time.

**Key size**

In cryptography, you have three major elements.

The plaintext, the ciphertext and the key.

The key is combined with the encryption algorithm to encrypt the plaintext, and get the ciphertext. It's like the state of a function, that is:

```
 K = "This is the key".
 P = "Plaintext".
 C = Encrypt(P,K).

 // This would result in some ciphertext.
```

If K was not equal to "This is the key", and was equal to "This is another key", then the value of C would be different.

The keysize is the size of the key used. For example, AES256 uses a 256 bit key. That means that the key is literally 256 binary numbers long.

*What is the difference between 128 bit encryption and 1024 bit encryption?*

The difference is in the title. 128 bit encryption encrypts data with a 128 bit key. 1024 bit encryption encrypts with 1024 bits of data. The important thing to note here is that with 128 bits, you're usually looking at a [Symmetric Key Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm), and with 1024 bits, you're usually looking at an [Asymmetric Encryption Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).

**Brute Force Attack**

Yes. Following the AES256 example, if you perform 2^256 possible combinations of a key, you will eventually crack any and all AES256 ciphers. However, 2^256 is a massive number, and it's considered computationally unfeasible to attempt that value.

Comment: So its mean the  K = "This is the key" long at most is 256 bit?

Comment: Not at most. ALWAYS. In 256 bit key encryption, the key HAS to be 256 bits long. I was just giving you an example :)

Comment: Well if it was my answer that got you there, be sure to mark it as correct :)

Comment: Is this possible to brute force the key of MD5 or MD4 ?

Comment: MD5 is whatis called a [Hashing Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) which mean it is a one way encryption. There is no key. What you CAN do though is use a Rainbow table. [here is an example of one](http://crackstation.net/)

Comment: "There is no key" so why we said MD5 has 128 bit key-size?

Comment: MD5 has a 128 bit message digest size. Not key size. Read my link.

Comment: A key and the plain text should never be strings for modern cryptography, it is not a good idea to use strings within an example. Passwords require a password based key derivation function to turn them into keys, and plaintext should be encoded using a character encoding method.

Comment: True, but OP didn't even understand the fundamental principles of encryption. Why throw in all that added detail when I'm trying to teach them the abstract principles?

Answer (score 0):

It means that with 2<sup>112</sup> trial encryptions, you can guarantee that you find the key that was used to encrypt something with 3DES. That, however, uses a "meet in the middle" (MITM) attack that also requires an absurd amount of memory.

Also note that 3DES only really needs 112 bits of key material. You do an encrypt/decrypt/encrypt (EDE, most common) or Decrypt/Encrypt/Decrypt (DED) cycle, but the first and last can use the same key. 168 bits means you're using a separate key for each cycle. That's fine, but not entirely necessary.

As far as what the key itself is, it's basically just a collection of bits that are known, but (by strong preference) difficult or impossible for anybody else to predict or guess. In a typical case, you don't directly use what the user has entered as a key. At the very least you run that through a cryptographic hash to get a constant-size result. Given the predictability of what user's typically enter, you often want to go a step further: generate a much more random key, and use the user's password only to allow access to that key. This means (for example) that although it may be fairly easy to recover the user's key given physical access to their computer, the data sent "over the wire" (where it's generally easier to intercept) uses a key that's much less predictable than their password itself.

A far as 128-bit vs. 1024 bit goes, the two aren't normally entirely comparable. A huge amount here depends on the difficulty of an attack. The worst case is generally a key-exhaustion attack. This basically means that you simply try every possible key until you find one that "works".

If that's the best attack known against an algorithm, then a key size around 128 bits is almost certainly adequate against almost any conceivable improvement of "conventional" technology--that is, even if we assume CPUs will continue to get a lot faster for a long time, and assume processors of tens or even hundreds of Tera-Hertz can be build, carrying out 2<sup>128</sup> operations to exhaust the key space still remains completely impractical (like, with millions of 100 Tera-Hertz processors, you still don't finish before the heat-death of the universe).

Larger key sizes with symmetric encryption are *largely* intended to protect against practical quantum computers. A (working) quantum computer of sufficient capacity can carry out different types of attacks than conventional computers, and could exhaust a key space much more quickly than a conventional computer. So that's the source of things AES 256.

When you get to keys substantially larger than that, you're typically dealing with encryption like RSA, for which practical attacks are known which do *not* involve doing trial encryption until you find a key that "works". In the case of RSA, part of the information that needs to be publicly known can be (fairly easily) converted to a large number that's a product of two prime numbers. If you can factor that number to obtain those two primes, you can break the encryption fairly easily.

So in this case, the strength we need is based on that product being large enough that factoring it is impractical. The largest number that would be suitable to use as an RSA key that's publicly known to have been factored was 768 bits.

So, if you're interested in safety vs. a well equipped attacker, for RSA you pretty clearly need a key larger than that.

Note that the "meet in the middle" attack on 2DES, the attack on 2-key 3DES and factoring large RSA keys have some characteristics in common: that make attacking them quite different from attacking plain DES. With DES, you can easily trade off between how much you spend, and how fast you get a result. Spend (nearly) nothing, and it takes a *long* time to get a result, but you will eventually. The more you're willing to spend, the faster you get your result.

With the other attacks, however, you need a large amount of memory to carry out the attack at all. For these, you (mostly) can't just scale things so spending half as much gets you a result half as fast. Rather, you'd need to switch to (for example) using SSD instead of DRAM for your storage--and immediately lose a *lot* of speed. Alternatively, you could switch to another algorithm that's asymptotically less favorable, but doesn't have quite such a high barrier to entry. Again, for a practical attack you'll typically lose a lot very quickly this way.

Bottom line: for some attacks, you get a fairly "smooth" trade-off between time and money. With others, you get much more of a step function; in many cases, a practical attack will simply exceed most people's capacity (now and for quite a while to come, in most cases).

Comment: That would be pass phrase, there is no such thing as a key phrase. You should use a PBKDF (password based key derivation function) to turn the password input into a randomized key. Also note that 2 key triple DES has a different security margin than 3 key triple DES.

Comment: 2TDEA (3DES with K1=K3) provides 80 bits or less of effective strength, and that's not good enough. Only the 3-key version could be considered strong encryption, and that just barely.

Comment: @erickson: I'd advise that you look at how you attack 2-key 3DES. Yes, there *is* [an attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/25624/479) that (based on the block size) has a complexity *around* 2^{64}--but it also requires about 2^{60} bytes of RAM. Current worldwide DRAM production capacity is somewhere around 2^{50} bytes annually (probably a little less than that). That means (assuming Moore's law holds out) that around 10 years from now, the entire earth's production of DRAM for an entire year would be (barely) sufficient to start the attack.

Comment: @erickson: Bottom line: you're taking a *lot* for granted in saying "that's not good enough". Most people never protect anything that would justify an attack this expensive--and the few who do need to worry more about "practical cryptanalysis" (e.g., somebody kidnapping them and torturing them to get the key). That's mostly irrelevant though: the question isn't about how many bits is enough--it's about what N bits of strength *means*.

Comment: We don't know everything there is to know about cryptanalysis. Stronger encryption provides a safety margin to protect against future (or currently undisclosed) attacks. In an AES world, 80-bit encryption isn't something I want to have to defend.

Comment: @erickson: The question had nothing to do with whether 3DES is currently a good choice of encryption algorithm. It was about what "N-bit keysize" means. Nothing more and nothing less.

Answer (score -1):

The wikipedia has an entry on the key size: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_size